# Faster drop-in replacement for bash `cut` for specific application

Tags: c, bash, performance, awk, cut

I have a very large tab separated file. The tab separated file is binary and will be streamed by the tool `samtools` (which is very fast and not the bottleneck). Now I want to output only the content up to the first tab.

In my current piped command `cut` is the bottleneck:

```
samtools view -@ 15 -F 0x100 file.bam | cut -f 1 | pigz > out.gz
```

I tried using `awk '{print $1}'. This is not sufficiently faster I also tried using` parallel`in combination with`cut` but this also does not increase the speed much.

I guess it would be better to have a tool which just outputs the string until first tab and then completely skips the entire line.

Do you have a suggestion for a tool which is faster for my purpose? Ideally, one would write a small C program I guess but my C is a bit rusty so would take too long for me.

Comment: Just an idea: if you know for sure for example tab occures in the first 20bytes in all lines, try `|cut -b20 | cut -f1`

Comment: Thanks @gabor.zed. This is a bit faster indeed. But not sufficient for my application.

Comment: maybe try to `unbuffer` stdout.

Comment: @kvantour Thanks, but does not work for me. Or how exactly would you do this? Just adding to the command above? Like: stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 samtools view -@ 15 -F 0x100 file.bam | cut -f1 | pigz > out.gz

Comment: My feeling is that even with a specifically written C program, you would not get that much speed advantage. For testing this idea, I suggest that you remove your `cut` completely. The result will of course be incorrect, but if this still isn't much faster either, you know at least that the `cut` itself isn't your bottleneck

Comment: @Michael : Shouldn't you do a `stdbuf` for all commands in the pipe, and not only for `samtools`?

Comment: @user1934428 I think "cut" is the bottleneck. I did: 1) samtools view -@ 15 -F 0x100 file.bam > /dev/null and 2) samtools view -@ 15 -F 0x100 file.bam | cut -f1 > /dev/null. The first one is 2.5 times faster. I piped to /dev/null to make sure that we do not have a difference because the first output is larger so pigz could be slower.

Comment: @kvantour and putting stdbuf in front of all commands makes it even slower.

Comment: What awk are you using (what is output of `awk --version`)?

Comment: @Daweo GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)

Comment: Off-topic: Do you guys know why someone would mark this question to be closed? I think it is a valid question, no?

Comment: How big is a single line of data which the tool `samtools` returns?

Comment: @kvantour Up to about 400 characters

Comment: @Michael : In your OP you wrote _Do you have a suggestion for a tool which is faster_ , and this is not a programming question, but a request for recommending some tool. Therefore it does not fit the guidelines for stackoverflow. Also, the discussion shows that we don't even know exactly where the blocking point is: It could be the time needed to set up the pipe, or the time for scanning a string. If you want to know more, you would have to use something like _strace_, to analyze where the time actually has been spent.

Comment: Thinking of it: Setting I/O to unbuffered shouldn't speed up things. In contrary. After all, buffering was invented in order to make I/O faster. You could try to re-do your buffering experiment, but using very large buffers instead. Ah, and don't fiddle with stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I hacked a small C program which directly filters the BAM file and also writes to a gzip -- with a lot of help of the htslib developers (which is the basis for samtools).

So piping is not needed any more. This solution is about 3-4 times faster than the solution with the C code above (from Stephan).

See here:
https://github.com/samtools/samtools/issues/1672

Answer (score 2):

You are interested in a small C program that just outputs lines from stdin until first tab.

In C you can do this easily with something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024

int main(void) {
    char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL) {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n\t")] = '\0';
        fputs(buf, stdout);
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It simply reads lines with `fgets` from stdin. The string is terminated with a NUL byte at the first tab `\t`. The same applies if there is a `\n` to have no extra line feeds in the output, just in case there is no tab on an input line.

Whether this is much faster in your use case I cannot say, but it should at least provide a starting point for trying out your idea.

Comment: Thanks much! Yes, this takes only half the time from my above command using "cut" and is the fastest solution so far (while being super simple). But it would be important to speed my approach up even more but I guess from here on it will be hard!?

Comment: One should only remember to compile the C program with optimizations enabled. In my use cases, I have often seen C's file stream functions work quite optimally. I am also curious about other solutions.

Comment: Since the program is so simple, I fear that the compiler can't do much optimizations. For better speed, we should slurp the whole stdin into memory at once, and then using a pointer inside the array for the actual work. To do this, we would need to know how big the input can be. In this case, we could set the output buffer of samtools and the input buffer of the C-program to that size.

Answer (score 1):

*GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)*

You might give a try other implementation of AWK, according to test done in 2009¹ [Don’t MAWK AWK – the fastest and most elegant big data munging language!](https://brenocon.com/blog/2009/09/dont-mawk-awk-the-fastest-and-most-elegant-big-data-munging-language/) `nawk` was found faster than `gawk` and `mawk` was found faster than `nawk`. You would need to run test with your data to find if using other implementation give noticeable boost.

¹so versions available in 2022 might give different result

Comment: gawk has gone through significant performance improvements since then and runs far faster now.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider process-substitutions instead of a pipeline.

```
$ < <( < <(samtools view -@ 15 -F 0x100 file.bam) cut -f1 )  pigz
```

**Note:** I'm using process substitution to generate `stdin` and avoid using another FIFO. This seems to be much faster.

I've written a simple test script `sam_test.sh` that generates some output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo {1..10000} | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{$1=$1;for(i=1;i<=1000;++i) print i,$0}'
```

and compared the output of the following commands:

```
$ ./sam_test.sh | cut -f1 | awk '!(FNR%3)'
$ < <(./sam_test.sh) cut -f1 | awk '!(FNR%3)'
$ < <( < <(./sam_test.sh) cut -f1 ) awk '!(FNR%3)'
```

The later of the three cases is in 'runtime' significantly faster. Using `strace -c` , we can see that each pipeline adds a significant amount of `wait4` syscalls. The final version is then also significantly faster (factor 700 in the above case).

---

**Output of test case (short):**

```
$ cat ./sam_test_full_pipe.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./sam_test.sh | cut -f1 - | awk '!(FNR%3)' -
$ strace -c ./sam_test_full_pipe.sh > /dev/null
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 99.22    0.643249      160812         4         1 wait4
  0.30    0.001951           5       334       294 openat
  0.21    0.001331           5       266       230 stat
  0.04    0.000290          20        14        12 execve
<snip>
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.648287         728       890       549 total
```

```
$ cat ./sam_test_one_pipe.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
< <(./sam_test.sh) cut -f1 - | awk '!(FNR%3)' -
$ strace -c ./sam_test_one_pipe.sh > /dev/null
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 98.72    0.256664       85554         3         1 wait4
  0.45    0.001181           3       334       294 openat
  0.29    0.000757           2       266       230 stat
<snip>
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.259989         295       881       547 total
```

```
$ cat ./sam_test_no_pipe.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
< <(< <(./sam_test.sh) cut -f1 - ) awk '!(FNR%3)' -
$ strace -c ./sam_test_no_pipe.sh > /dev/null
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 39.43    0.002863        1431         2         1 wait4
 19.68    0.001429           4       334       294 openat
 14.87    0.001080           3       285       242 stat
 10.00    0.000726          51        14        12 execve
 <snip>
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.007261           7       909       557 total
```

**Output of test case (full):**

```
$ cat ./sam_test_full_pipe.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./sam_test.sh | cut -f1 - | awk '!(FNR%3)' -
$ strace -c ./sam_test_full_pipe.sh > /dev/null
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 99.22    0.643249      160812         4         1 wait4
  0.30    0.001951           5       334       294 openat
  0.21    0.001331           5       266       230 stat
  0.04    0.000290          20        14        12 execve
  0.04    0.000276           6        42           mmap
  0.04    0.000229          76         3           clone
  0.03    0.000178           3        49         4 close
  0.02    0.000146           3        39           fstat
  0.02    0.000109           9        12           mprotect
  0.01    0.000080           5        16           read
  0.01    0.000053           2        18           rt_sigprocmask
  0.01    0.000052           3        16           rt_sigaction
  0.01    0.000038           3        10           brk
  0.01    0.000036          18         2           munmap
  0.01    0.000034           5         6         2 access
  0.00    0.000029           3         8         1 fcntl
  0.00    0.000024           3         7           lseek
  0.00    0.000019           4         4         3 ioctl
  0.00    0.000019           9         2           pipe
  0.00    0.000018           3         5           getuid
  0.00    0.000018           3         5           getgid
  0.00    0.000018           3         5           getegid
  0.00    0.000017           3         5           geteuid
  0.00    0.000013           4         3           dup2
  0.00    0.000013          13         1           faccessat
  0.00    0.000009           2         4         2 arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000008           4         2           getpid
  0.00    0.000008           4         2           prlimit64
  0.00    0.000005           5         1           sysinfo
  0.00    0.000004           4         1           write
  0.00    0.000004           4         1           uname
  0.00    0.000004           4         1           getppid
  0.00    0.000003           3         1           getpgrp
  0.00    0.000002           2         1           rt_sigreturn
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.648287         728       890       549 total
```

```
$ cat ./sam_test_one_pipe.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
< <(./sam_test.sh) cut -f1 - | awk '!(FNR%3)' -
$ strace -c ./sam_test_one_pipe.sh > /dev/null
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 98.72    0.256664       85554         3         1 wait4
  0.45    0.001181           3       334       294 openat
  0.29    0.000757           2       266       230 stat
  0.11    0.000281          20        14        12 execve
  0.08    0.000220           5        42           mmap
  0.06    0.000159          79         2           clone
  0.05    0.000138           3        45         2 close
  0.05    0.000125           3        39           fstat
  0.03    0.000083           6        12           mprotect
  0.02    0.000060           3        16           read
  0.02    0.000054           3        16           rt_sigaction
  0.02    0.000042           2        16           rt_sigprocmask
  0.01    0.000038           6         6         2 access
  0.01    0.000035          17         2           munmap
  0.01    0.000027           2        10           brk
  0.01    0.000019           3         5           getuid
  0.01    0.000018           3         5           geteuid
  0.01    0.000017           3         5           getgid
  0.01    0.000017           3         5           getegid
  0.00    0.000010           1         7           lseek
  0.00    0.000009           2         4         3 ioctl
  0.00    0.000008           4         2           getpid
  0.00    0.000007           1         4         2 arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000005           5         1           sysinfo
  0.00    0.000004           4         1           uname
  0.00    0.000003           3         1           getppid
  0.00    0.000003           3         1           getpgrp
  0.00    0.000003           1         2           prlimit64
  0.00    0.000002           2         1           rt_sigreturn
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           write
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           pipe
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           dup2
  0.00    0.000000           0         8         1 fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           faccessat
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.259989         295       881       547 total
```

```
$ cat ./sam_test_no_pipe.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
< <(< <(./sam_test.sh) cut -f1 - ) awk '!(FNR%3)' -
$ strace -c ./sam_test_no_pipe.sh > /dev/null
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 39.43    0.002863        1431         2         1 wait4
 19.68    0.001429           4       334       294 openat
 14.87    0.001080           3       285       242 stat
 10.00    0.000726          51        14        12 execve
  2.67    0.000194           4        42           mmap
  1.83    0.000133           3        39           fstat
  1.67    0.000121         121         1           clone
  1.58    0.000115           2        41           close
  0.88    0.000064           6        10         2 access
  0.87    0.000063           5        12           mprotect
  0.73    0.000053           3        16           rt_sigaction
  0.70    0.000051           4        12           rt_sigprocmask
  0.66    0.000048           3        16           read
  0.48    0.000035           3        10           brk
  0.48    0.000035           3         9           getuid
  0.44    0.000032          16         2           munmap
  0.41    0.000030           3         8         1 fcntl
  0.41    0.000030           3         9           geteuid
  0.40    0.000029           3         9           getegid
  0.34    0.000025           2         9           getgid
  0.22    0.000016           5         3           dup2
  0.21    0.000015           3         4         3 ioctl
  0.19    0.000014           2         7           lseek
  0.18    0.000013          13         1           faccessat
  0.12    0.000009           2         4         2 arch_prctl
  0.11    0.000008           4         2           prlimit64
  0.08    0.000006           3         2           getpid
  0.06    0.000004           4         1           write
  0.06    0.000004           4         1           rt_sigreturn
  0.06    0.000004           4         1           uname
  0.06    0.000004           4         1           sysinfo
  0.06    0.000004           4         1           getppid
  0.06    0.000004           4         1           getpgrp
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.007261           7       909       557 total
```

Comment: For some reason this was not faster in my case...

Answer (score 1):

In the question OP has mentioned that `awk '{print $1}'` is not sufficiently faster than `cut`; in my testing I'm seeing `awk` running about twice as fast as `cut`, so not sure how OP is using `awk` ... or if I'm missing something (basic) with my testing ...

OP has mentioned a 'large' tab-delimited file with up to 400 characters per line; we'll simulate this with the following code that generates a ~400MB file:

```
$ cat sam_out.awk
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t"; x="1234567890"
        for (i=1;i<=40;i++)      filler=filler x
        for (i=1;i<=1000000;i++) print x,filler
      }'
$ . ./sam_out.awk | wc
1000000 2000000 412000000
```

Test calls:

```
$ cat sam_tests.sh
echo "######### pipe to cut"
time . ./sam_out.awk | cut -f1 -         > /dev/null

echo "######### pipe to awk"
time . ./sam_out.awk | awk '{print $1}'  > /dev/null

echo "######### process-sub to cut"
time cut -f1          <(. ./sam_out.awk) > /dev/null

echo "######### process-sub to awk"
time awk '{print $1}' <(. ./sam_out.awk) > /dev/null
```

**NOTE:** also ran all 4 tests with output written to 4 distinct output files; `diff` of the 4 output files showed all were the same (`wc`: `1000000  1000000 11000000`; `head -1`: `1234567890`)

Results of running the tests:

```
######### pipe to cut

real    0m1.177s
user    0m0.205s
sys     0m1.454s

######### pipe to awk

real    0m0.582s
user    0m0.166s
sys     0m0.759s

######### process-sub to cut

real    0m1.265s
user    0m0.351s
sys     0m1.746s

######### process-sub to awk

real    0m0.655s
user    0m0.097s
sys     0m0.968s
```

**NOTES:**

- test system: Ubuntu 10.04, `cut` (GNU coreutils 8.30), `awk` (GNU Awk 5.0.1)
- earlier version of this answer showed `awk` running 14x-15x times faster than `cut`; that system: cygwin 3.3.5, `cut` (GNU coreutils 8.26), `awk` (GNU Awk 5.1.1)

Comment: When you change the process-substitution from FIFO to stdin (`< <(cmd)` ) it will work faster (see my answer below)

Comment: @kvantour: on my systems I'm showing comparable times for `. ./sam_out.awk | awk '{print $1}'` vs `< <(. ./sam_out.awk) awk '{print $1}' ` vs `awk '{print $1}' <(. ./sam_out.awk)`; also verified all 3 commands generate the same exact output; I'm wondering if there could be some OS-level setting in your system that could be causing the large timing differences you're seeing ... ?

Comment: Which Shell do you use? There might be differences between bash and zsh

Comment: bash 5.0.17 and bash 4.4.12

Comment: I stand corrected on my earlier comment that awk can't be faster than cut, I see similar results on my laptop running cygwin where awk takes less than half the time of cut. I can't imagine why.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need first field why not just

```
{m,n,g}awk NF=1 FS='\t'
```

In terms of performance, I don't have a tab file handy but i do have 12.5mn rows `1.85 GB` `.txt` with plenty of `multi-byte UTF-8` in it that's `"="` separated :

```
 rows = 12,494,275. | ascii+utf8 chars = 1,285,316,715. | bytes = 1,983,544,693.

  -  4.44s mawk 2
  -  4.95s mawk 1
  - 10.48s gawk 5.1.1
  - 40.07s nawk
```

Why some enjoy pushing for the slow `awk`s is beyond me.

=

```
      in0: 35.8MiB 0:00:00 [ 357MiB/s] [ 357MiB/s] [> ]  1% ETA 0:00:00
     out9:  119MiB 0:00:04 [27.0MiB/s] [27.0MiB/s] [ <=>   ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:04 [ 428MiB/s] [ 428MiB/s] [======>] 100%            
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | mawk2 NF=1 FS==; )  
4.34s user 0.45s system 107% cpu 4.439 total

     1  52888940993baac8299b49ee2f5bdee7  stdin
```

=

```
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:04 [ 384MiB/s] [ 384MiB/s] [=====>] 100%            
     out9:  119MiB 0:00:04 [24.2MiB/s] [24.2MiB/s] [ <=>]

( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | mawk NF=1 FS==; )  
4.83s user 0.47s system 107% cpu 4.936 total

     1  52888940993baac8299b49ee2f5bdee7  stdin
```

=

```
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:10 [ 180MiB/s] [ 180MiB/s] [ ==>] 100%            
     out9:  119MiB 0:00:10 [11.4MiB/s] [11.4MiB/s] [ <=>]

( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | gawk NF=1 FS==; )  
10.36s user 0.56s system 104% cpu 10.476 total

     1  52888940993baac8299b49ee2f5bdee7  stdin
```

=

```
      in0: 4.25MiB 0:00:00 [42.2MiB/s] [42.2MiB/s] [> ]  0% ETA 0:00:00
     out9:  119MiB 0:00:40 [2.98MiB/s] [2.98MiB/s] [<=> ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:40 [47.2MiB/s] [47.2MiB/s] [=====>] 100%            

( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | nawk NF=1 FS==; )  
39.79s user 0.88s system 101% cpu 40.068 total

     1  52888940993baac8299b49ee2f5bdee7  stdin
```

But these pale compared to using the right `FS` to collect everything away :

***barely 1.95 secs***

```
   ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | mawk2 NF-- FS='=.*$'; )  
    1.83s user 0.42s system 115% cpu 1.951 total

 1  52888940993baac8299b49ee2f5bdee7  stdin
```

By comparison, even `gnu-cut` that is purely C-code binary is slower :

```
 ( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | gcut -d= -f 1; )  
 2.53s user 0.50s system 113% cpu 2.674 total

 1  52888940993baac8299b49ee2f5bdee7  stdin
```

You can save a tiny bit (**`1.772 secs`**) more using a more verbose approach :

```
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | mawk2 '{ print $1 }' FS='=.*$'; ) 
1.64s user 0.42s system 116% cpu 1.772 total

 1  52888940993baac8299b49ee2f5bdee7  stdin
```

Unfortunately, complex `FS` really isn't `gawk`'s forte, even after you give it a helping boost with the byte-level flag :

```
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | gawk -F'=.+$' -be NF--; )  

20.23s user 0.59s system 102% cpu 20.383 total
52888940993baac8299b49ee2f5bdee7  stdin
```